# Slide pane in impress not on the left side

Tags: libreoffice

I accidentally moved my slide pane in Impress from the left side and I don't know how to put it back.

Answer (score 1):

Just click and drag the pane from the title "slides" to its original position.

I hope this will be useful for you, let me know it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when you just drag it back to the original position it doesn't do it but if you do the following it works.

1. Drag it to the bottom right corner (over the task pane).
2. Release (dock) it there.
3. Drag it again to its original position

At least that's what happens on my computer.
Hope it helps.